# I couldn't find my PHP error, it gives me an T_ELSE

Tags: php, performance, gallery

It gives me this error could anyone help me please?
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\wamp64\www\photogallery\includes\gallery-upload.inc.php on line 59

Her is my code I hope you can help me. I couldn't find my error.
Could someone answer now I need it for my exam and that's about 2 hours.

```
$newFileName = $_POST['filename'];
if(empty(empty($newFileName))) {
    $newFileName = "gallery";
} else {
    $newFileName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $newFileName));
}
$imageTitle = $_POST['filetitle'];
$imageDesc = $_POST[''];

$file = $_FILES['file'];

$fileName = $file["name"];
$fileType = $file["type"];
$fileTempName = $file["tmp_name"];
$fileError = $file["error"];
$fileSize = $file["size"];

$fileExt = explode($fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
    if ($fileError === 0) {
        if(fileSize < 2000000) {
        $imageFullName = $newFileName ."." . uniqid("", true) ."." . $fileActualExt;
        $fileDestination = "../img/gallery/" . $imageFullName;

        include_once "dbh.inc.php";
        if (empty($imageTitle) || empty($imageDesc)) {
            header("Location: ../gallery.php?upload=empty");
            exit();
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                echo "SQL statement failed!";
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                $setImageOrder = $rowCount + 1;

                $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (titleGallery, descGallery, imgFullNameGallery, orderGallery) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                echo "SQL statement failed!";
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $imageTitle, $imageDesc, $imageFullName, $setImageOrder);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $fileDestination);

                header("Location: ../gallery.php?upload=succes");
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "File size is to big";
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "You had an error!";
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "You need to upload a proper file type!";
        exit();
    }
```

}
?>

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I can't edit the code. Please give some explanation then show the code

Answer (score 0):

This error means that there is something missing immediately before the ELSE statement. It says `unexpected 'else'` which means that it was expecting something else before the `else`.

It is likely that the code is missing a semi-colon or closing brace on the previous line. However, if you post your code around line 59 of the `gallery-upload.inc.php` file we can provide you with a more definite answer. Where did you get this file from?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use multiple else which result in the above error.
Error code:

```
if (condition) {
    echo 'test';
} else {
    echo "File size is to big";
    exit();
} else {
    echo "You had an error!";
    exit();
} else {
    echo "You need to upload a proper file type!";
    exit();
}
```

Use else-if with the condition.

```
if (condition) {
   //something
} else if (condition) {
   //something
} else {
   //something
}
```

Hope this helps! Tq